# IRS Statistics of Income, machine-readable

Tags: data-request, usa, government, economics, irs

Does anyone know of anyone else who has compiled a machine-readable set of the IRS's SOI Tax Stats - Historical Table 2, i.e., [these](http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-Historic-Table-2)?

The .xls files available from the IRS are crosstabbed and contain multiple subcategories. Difficult to translate to something database compliant for analysis.

Comment: i'd say these already are open data.  importing them into a single file would take maybe an hour of coding in R..

Comment: I think you guys may be underestimating the nuances in the file structure across years. I've been at it with python for a while now.  Of course, it's equally likely you're overestimating my programming ability, but both are sort of off-topic.

Comment: @Mac : could you tell is what questions you're trying to answer from the data, as that might affect recommendations of how the data needs to be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been slightly inattentive here, but for posterity's sake, I wanted to post the results of my cleaning effort: [machine-readable SOI data](https://github.com/DallasMorningNews/IRS-statistic-of-income).

Like most intensive data cleaning I've been a part of, it wasn't the result of a single programming effort. For example, a fair bit of consideration went in to how to reconcile the individual annual series. The coverage.csv in the repo shows the series coverage for 1997-2011. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

using scraperwiki, i can parse the .xls just fine. place the url in the input field, after it is done uploading, select download as spreadsheet, and you'll get .csv/.xlsx.

not an answer to the question(s) you posed directly, but an answer nonetheless. hope its useful...

Comment: Can you please expand on the answer?

Comment: sure, but not sure on what part. can you be more specific?

Comment: um ... explain how to convert crosstabbed .xls files to something for analysis? .. so it's then an answer to the question being asked.  If not, this should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: totally lost me on that one @joe....sorry. change this to a comment? i think it does what was asked...but if you disagree, i'll edit

Comment: @albert : My take on the question was that the second paragraph was the significant part -- not conversion of .xls to .xlsx or .csv

Comment: i thought i got that too...csv conversion helps there. i should note you get each table in its own csv, as well as another csv containing all the data....if that's off, sorry, lmk, i'll delete the whole thang

Comment: The question is not about parsing a single XLS, but *normalizing* many XLS with possibly subtle changes per state and year and how to cope with that.