# Are zip-code-level IRS income tax data available for every year, in machine-readable fomat?

Tags: data-request, usa, economics, taxes, irs

The IRS publishes [income tax data by zip code](http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-Individual-Income-Tax-Statistics-ZIP-Code-Data-%28SOI%29) for certain years (1998, 2001, 2004-2008 etc.) but a) certain years are missing, like 1999 and 2000, and b) only for 2008 and afterwards are the data provided in CSV format (it's in the zip file) in a consistent format. Are these data available from elsewhere? I'm guessing they're not because in [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1949/3565) similar issues came up and people talked about how the IRS isnt really forthcoming about this. If nothing comes up here I'll try a phone call and see what they can provide me.

Comment: If there's no answers, you'll likely want to see : http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/42/263 ; http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/171/263 ; http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1902/263

Comment: @Joe Thanks, I may end up having to do that but hopefully it won't come to that.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but thee is county-level data for a few more years at http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-County-Data but the formats also vary :(

Comment: Sophie Raseman should be able to help from the U.S. Department of Treasury: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/233/sophie-raseman

Comment: @MichaelA If you have found something from your research, can you come back to answer your question.

Comment: @philshem I and several other people from my institution wrote the IRS, and they responded that they are not making these data available for any remaining years, nor will they provide CSV files for any of the years that don't already have them. They provided no further details except that they have no plans to provide these data now or any time in the future.

Comment: Consider a FOIA request, especially for the missing years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @MichaelA (in the comments), zip code level IRS income machine-readable income data is not available for every year, and the IRS has no plans to do so/isn't very receptive to the idea

edit:
You can get all the data based on county/city (not zip) for the years 1989-2010 here:
http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-County-Data
So not the exact format you asked for, but its something to work with and also covers the years you are missing and then some.
I took this data and scraped out the information for Virginia, which you can view here:
http://data.openva.com/dataset

Comment: this sounds like a job for the opendatase datahub.io account!